# My peek() method will not return the head of my queue

Tags: java, queue

I have a QueueRunner class made. I am trying to figure out out to iterate to the head of my queue after poll() or offer() to return the head of my queue using peek().  I am having trouble returning the head or front of the queue though.

```
Public class Queue<T> {
private ArrayList<T> elements;

public Queue() {
    this.elements = new ArrayList<T>();
}

/**
* Offers an element to the end of the queue.
*
* @param    T   item
*/
public void offer(T element) {
    this.elements.add(element);
}

/**
* Peeks at, but does not remove, the element at the head of the queue.
*
* @return   T
*/
public T peek() {
    if(this.elements.size()==0) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return this.elements;
    // return this.elements.get(this.elements.size()-1);
    }
}

/**
* Polls an element from the head of the queue.
*
* @return   T
*/
public T poll() {
    return this.elements.remove(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.elements.get(0)` would return you the head/front of the queue. Since a queue is FIFO, the first element that was added will be the first to go and thus the head of the queue.

Comment: Thank you.  Such an easy fix.  Using get(i) in Queue and Stack always get the element at index i?

Comment: Depends on the underlying implementation. In most cases yes, since a list is used to implement a queue, to get an element at index I elements.get(I) is used. For a stack the head of the stack would be the last element. Do upvote the answer if it helped :)

Comment: won't allow me upvote. I'm not at rep 15 yet.  I understand FIFO(queue) and LIFO(stack).  I didn't realize get(i) was "built in" to List or ArrayList, but it makes sense if you think of Objects being referenced at particular indices in particular arrays.

Comment: Please let me know if I am using incorrect terminology or explaining my understanding of how this works improperly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are returning the `ArrayList<T>` itself not an element and returning the last element is commented out.

`else {
        return this.elements;
    // return this.elements.get(this.elements.size()-1);
    }`

Comment: I had the commented part out as a "guide" to use from my Stack class that I did before this.   Thank you.